# Load a file into a buffer without changing the display

Tags: find-file

I have a `use-package` idle hook that loads my org files into buffers for future use. I want this to be unobtrusive. However, I cannot find any `find-file` function which loads a file without changing the display.

There are a number of `find-file` functions in the Emacs manual, but none of these do what I want.

> `find-file` Visit a file.
>
> `find-file-read-only` Visit a file for viewing, without allowing changes to it.
>
> `find-alternate-file` Visit a different file instead of the one visited last.
>
> `find-file-other-window` Visit a file, in another window.
>
> `find-file-other-frame` Visit a file, in a new frame.
>
> `find-file-literally` Visit a file with no conversion of the contents.

I thought `find-file-literally` might be a winner, but it does in fact load the file into the current window.

Is there a function I can use to load files into buffers without any display changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you want is `find-file-noselect`.

> This function is the guts of all the file-visiting functions. It returns a buffer visiting the file filename. You may make the buffer current or display it in a window if you wish, but this function does not do so.